# Extension of Monotone Convergence Theorem and Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, signed-measures

A very simple question: Do the Monotone Convergence Theorem and Dominated Convergence Theorems hold for *signed* measures? In particular, if $\mu$ is a signed measure and $f_{n} \to f$ pointwise a.e., is it true that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_{n} d \mu= \int f d \mu
$$
if the conditions of the either of the theorems are met? If so, how would one prove and extension of these theorems?

Comment: Every signed measure can be decomposed as $\mu=\mu_+-\mu_-$ where $\mu_{\pm}$ are (non-signed) measure...

Answer (score 5):

Let $X$ be the underlying space. Let $P, N$ be a Hahn decomposition of $X$. Let $\mu^{+}, \mu^{-}$ be the corresponding Jordan decomposition of $\mu$. Then
$$
\int_{X} f_{n} d\mu = \int_{P} f_{n} d\mu^{+} - \int_{N} f_{n} d\mu^{-}.
$$
You can then apply whatever theorem you like to each integral on the right-hand side separately.