# Duality pairing between finite signed measures and bounded continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a metric space, $C_b(E)$ denote the set of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $E$ and $\mathcal M(E)$ denote the set of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$.

How can we show that $$\langle f,\mu\rangle:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\;\;\;\text{for }(f,\mu)\in C_b(E)\times\mathcal M(E)$$ is a duality pairing between $C_b(E)$ and $\mathcal M(E)$? Do we need impose further restrictions on $E$ (e.g. completeness and/or separability) and/or $\mathcal M(E)$ (e.g. regularity of the measures)?

We need to show that \begin{align}\forall f\in C_b(E)\setminus\{0\}&:\exists\mu\in\mathcal M(E)&:\langle f,\mu\rangle\ne0\tag1;\\\forall\mu\in\mathcal M(E)\setminus\{0\}&:\exists f\in C_b(E)&:\langle f,\mu\rangle\ne0\tag2.\end{align}

$(1)$ Should be easy. If $f\in C_b(E)\setminus\{0\}$, there is a $x\in E$ with $f(x)\ne 0$. Now we can choose $\mu$ to be the Dirac measure $\delta_x$ concentrated at $x$ and obtain $\langle f,\mu\rangle=f(x)\ne0$.

But how can we show $(2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C$ is any closed set and $U_n=\{x: d(x,C) <\frac 1 n\}$ then there exist continuous functions $f_n : E \to [0,1]$ such that $f_n(x)=1$ for all $x \in C$ and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x \notin U_n$. Since $\int f_n d\mu=0$ for all $n$ we get $\mu (C)=0$. If we write $\mu$ as $\mu_1-\mu_2$ where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are positive finite measures then we get $\mu_1(C)=\mu_2(C)$ for any closed set $C$. You can use $\pi -\lambda$ Theorem  to show that $\mu_1=\mu_2$.

Comment: What exactly have you shown? Did you start with the contrary assumption that there is a $\mu\in\mathcal M(E)\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\langle f,\mu\rangle=0$ for all $f\in C_b(E)$? I've read that the "regularity of the measures yields that $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ is a duality pairing", but do we really need regularity at some point?

Comment: There are different types of regularity. Any finite Borel measure on  metric space has the regularity property $\mu (A)=\sup \{\mu (C): C \text {closed}, C \subset A\}$. @0xbadf00d

Comment: How do you define the notion of being a "Borel" measurable? Some authors imply mean *any* measure on a Borel $\sigma$-algebra by that term; others mean that $\mu(K)<\infty$ for every compact $K$. In any case, did you use $\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(C):C\text{ closed },C\subseteq A\}$ at some point?

Comment: Your question is about finite signed measures. Any such  measure defined on the Borel sigma algebra has the regularity property I have stated. (BTW Borel measure and Borel measurable are different terms. You cannot talk about  a measure being Borel measurable). @0xbadf00d

Comment: That was a typo. I inteded to write "being a Borel measure". Do you have a reference for your claim? And you didn't reply to my question: Did you use this identity somewhere?

Comment: I suggested use of $\pi -\lambda$ theorem to to by-pass regularity. If you know regularity then you don't have to use this theorem. The main point is $\mu (C)=0$ for all close sets $C$implies $\mu(A)=0$ for all Borel sets $A$.  @0xbadf00d

Comment: Do you have a reference anyway?

Comment: Convergence of Probability Measures by Billingsley. @0xbadf00d

Comment: I guess a possible choice for $f_n$ is $$f_n:=\frac{d(\;\cdot\;,U_n^c)}{d(\;\cdot\;,C)+d(\;\cdot\;,U_n^c)}.$$ However, I don't get how you conclude $\mu(C)=0$. Clearly, $C=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}U_n$, but wouldn't it be enough to consider a single $n$ or, alternatively, a single $f\in C_b(E)$ with $f\ge0$ and $\left.f\right|_C=1$? By assumption, $\int f\:{\rm d}\mu=0$ and hence $f=0$ $\mu$-a.e.; which is only possible when $\mu(C)=0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: $f \geq 0, \int fd\mu=0$ does not imply that $f=0$ a.e. since $\mu$ is not a positive measure.

Comment: @0xbadf00d thanks for bringing this to my attention. I agree that this answer is a little short on the details, but it seems to be correct. To get existence of the functions $f_n$, use Urysohn's lemma. To get $\mu(C) = 0$, use the dominated convergence theorem (also works for signed measures; e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3934032/)), since $f_n$ converges pointwise to $\chi_C$. The case $C = \varnothing$ or $C = E$ deserves separate treatment. For the final step, see [typical application of $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Example)).

Answer (score 4):

To put this result into context, I will show how to deduce it from the big theorems. (This is not nearly as elementary as Kavi's proof.)

Unfortunately, different authors use different notation / terminology, so let me set up a few definitions first.

> **Definition.** A *finitely additive signed measure* (or *charge*) is a function $\mu : \mathcal A \to [-\infty,\infty]$ with the following properties:
>
> - $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$;
> - $\mu$ assumes at most one of the values $-\infty$ and $+\infty$;
> - $\mu$ is finitely additive.
>
> Comparted to signed measures, the requirement of $\sigma$-additivity is weakened to finite additivity.

If $\Omega$ is a topological space, let $\mathcal A_\Omega$ and $\mathcal B_\Omega$ denote respectively the algebra and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open (or closed) sets of $\Omega$. Then $\mathcal A_\Omega \subseteq \mathcal B_\Omega$, and $\mathcal B_\Omega$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A_\Omega$, so every measure on $B_\Omega$ is uniquely determined by its values on $A_\Omega$.

> **Definition.** Let $\Omega$ be a topological space. We say that a finitely additive signed measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal A_\Omega$ is *regular* if for every $A \in \mathcal A_\Omega$ one has
> \begin{align*}
> \mu(A) &= \sup\{\mu(F) \, : \, F \subseteq A\ \text{closed}\} \\[1ex]
> &= \inf\,\{\mu(V) \: : \: V \supseteq A \ \text{open}\}.
> \end{align*}
> **Note.** Different authors use different notions of regularity. In particular, sometimes the closed sets $F \subseteq A$ are replaced by compact sets.

We will use the following well-known results:

> **Theorem.** *Let $\Omega$ be a normal Hausdorff space. Then $C_b(\Omega)'$ is isometrically isomorphic to the space $rba(\Omega)$ of all regular, finitely additive signed measures of bounded variation on $\mathcal A_\Omega$, equipped with the total variation norm.*
>
> See [DS58, Theorem IV.6.2 (p.262)] or [AB06, Theorem 14.10 (p.495)].
> For general topological spaces, see [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70611/reference-for-proof-that-c-b-rba).

> **Lemma.** *Every finite signed Borel measure on a metric space is regular.*
>
> See [DS58, Exercise III.9.22 (p.170)] or [AB06, Theorem 12.5 (p.436)], among others.
> (Side note: this is not true for the other notion of regularity, with compact sets instead of closed sets, as can be seen from [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22176).)

It follows that the space $\mathcal M(\Omega)$ of finite signed Borel measures is a subspace of $rba(\Omega) \cong C_b(\Omega)'$. To complete the proof, note that every normed space $X$ separates points on every subspace of $X'$: if $\varphi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$, then $\varphi = 0$.
<sub>(More generally, for a bilinear pairing $\langle E , F \rangle$ to be non-degenerate, so that it is a proper dual pairing, it is necessary and sufficient that the induced maps $E \to F^*$ and $F \to E^*$ are injective.)</sub>

**References.**

[DS58] Nelson Dunford, Jacob T. Schwartz, *Linear Operators, Part I: General Theory*, Interscience, 1958.

[AB06] Charalambos D. Aliprantis, Kim C. Border, *Infinite Dimensional Analysis, A Hitchhiker's Guide*, Third Edition, Springer, 2006.

Comment: The reason why $\mathcal M(E)$ (from the question) is only a subspace of your space $rba(E)$, is that I've defined $\mathcal M(E)$ to be a set of *finite* signed measures, which hence necessarily have bounded variation, but your $rba(E)$ might contain signed measures of bounded variation which take either the value $\infty$ or $-infty$, right? Or is there more on that?

Comment: @0xbadf00d no, the point is that $rba(\Omega)$ contains a larger class of set functions, namely the *finitely additive measures*. Compared to $\mathcal M(\Omega)$, the $\sigma$-additivity of measures is weakened to *finite* additivity. Clearly bounded variation implies finite (bounded, in fact), so everything in $rba(\Omega)$ is finite. However, I don't think the converse (finite implies bounded variation) is true for finitely additive measures; I think you need $\sigma$-additivity for that.