# Relation between weak topology on space of signed measures on a metric space $E$ and the weak* topology on $C_b(E)'$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

In general, if $E_i$ is a $\mathbb R$-vector space and $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ is a duality pairing between $E_1$ and $E_2$ and $$p_{x_2}(x_1):=q_{x_1}(x_2):=\left|\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\right|\;\;\;\text{for }(x_1,x_2)\in E_1\times E_2,$$ then $p_{x_2}$ is a seminorm on $E_1$ for all $x_2\in E_2$ and $q_{x_1}$ is a seminorm on $E_2$ for all $x_1\in E_1$.

Hence, $\left\{p_{x_2}:x_2\in E_2\right\}$ is inducing a locally convex topology $\sigma(E_1,E_2)$ on $E_1$ and $\left\{q_{x_1}:x_1\in E_1\right\}$ is inducing a locally convex topology $\sigma(E_2,E_1)$ on $E_2$.

If $\varphi\in E_1^\ast$, we can show that $\varphi$ is $\sigma(E_1,E_2)$-continuous iff $\varphi=\langle\;\cdot\;x_2\rangle$.

> By the aforementioned result, we are able to identify $$E_1':=\left\{\varphi\in E_1^\ast:\varphi\text{ is }\sigma(E_1,E_2)\text{-continuous}\right\}$$ with $E_2$. Does that mean $E_1'$ is again a locally convex topological vector space when endowed with the topology $\sigma(E_2,E_1)$?

I'm mainly interested in the following instance: Let $E_1:=C_b(E)$ be the set of real-valued bounded continuous functions on a metric space $E$, $E_2:=\mathcal M(E)$ denote the set of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $$\langle f,\mu\rangle:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\;\;\;\text{for }(f,\mu)\in C_b(E)\times\mathcal M(E).$$

> If $E_1=C_b(E)$ is equipped with the supremum norm, we may identify $\mathcal M(E)$ with a subset of $C_b(E)'$. How is $\sigma(E_2,E_1)$ related the the subspace topology on $\mathcal M(E)$ induced from the weak* topology on $C_b(E)'$?

Comment: Hm, the bounty does not seem to have increased the number of views by much. I think this is for the most part a functional analysis question, so maybe you should add the [tag:functional-analysis] tag, seeing as that's the tag most people are following.

Comment: Too bad you let the bounty expire. In any case, I hope my answer was useful to you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, $E_1'$ is a locally convex space when endowed with the $\sigma(E_1',E_1)$-topology. (It is just $E_2$ with the $\sigma(E_2,E_1)$-topology.)

Q2: The weak-$*$ topology respects subspaces. In general, if $\langle E, G \rangle$ is a dual pair and if $F \subseteq G$ is a subspace, then the relative $\sigma(G,E)$-topology on $F$ coincides with the $\sigma(F,E/F^\perp)$-topology.¹ If $F$ separates points on $E$, so that $\langle E,F\rangle$ is again a dual pair, then one has $F^\perp = \{0\}$, so now the $\sigma(F,E/F^\perp)$-topology is simply the $\sigma(F,E)$-topology.

<sub>¹: For a textbook reference, see [Sch99, §IV.4.1, Corollary 1 (p. 135)] or [Köt83, Proposition 22.2.(1) (p. 276)], among others. This is basically just a special case of the *transitive law of initial topologies* (see halfway through [this very long answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/)), since weak topologies and subspace topologies are examples of initial topologies.</sub>

In your example, we would have $E = C_b(\Omega)$, $F = \mathcal M(\Omega)$ and $G = C_b(\Omega)'$. It is easy to see that $\mathcal M(\Omega)$ separates points on $C_b(\Omega)$, so $F^\perp = \{0\}$. Furthermore, we know from [this other question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923330/) that $C_b(\Omega)$ separates points on $\mathcal M(\Omega)$, so $\mathcal M(\Omega)$ can be viewed as a subspace of $C_b(\Omega)'$. Hence we are in the setting described above.

**References**

[Köt83] Gottfried Köthe, *Topological Vector Spaces I*, Second revised printing, Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften 159, Springer, 1983.

[Sch99] H.H. Schaefer, with M.P. Wolff, *Topological Vector Spaces*, Second Edition, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 3, Springer, 1999.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) When you say what we exactly need to show to conclude that "$E_1'$ is just $E_2$ with the $\sigma(E_2,E_1)$-topology". In fact, I don't know whether we need to show anything at all or whether this is simply how we define the topology on $E_1'$. In the case of a normed space $E$, we usually equip $E'=\mathfrak L(E,\mathbb R)$ with the operator norm. And if we have a "representation result" as in the question of the form $E\cong F$ for some other normed space $F$, it usually means that there is an isometric isomorphism from $E$ to $F$.

Comment: (b) There's still an unanswered question in the comments below [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3923336/47771), but if this answer is correct, the bilinear pairing should always be non-degenerate, since every finite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a metric space has a certain regularity property. What do you think?

Comment: @0xbadf00d (a) we don't have to show anything at all, unless I misunderstood your original question. However, you make a good point that the weak-$*$ topology on $E_1'$ is not the usual norm topology. The norm dual is generalized by the so-called [strong topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_dual_space) on the dual of an arbitrary TVS. (b) Thanks for pointing that out; I wasn't aware of that.