# Relationship between dual spaces of $C_b(X)$ and $C_0(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let X be a non-compact, locally compact and $\sigma$-compact set (can be $\mathbb{R}^d$ for simplicity). Let $C_b(X)$ be the set of all bounded continuous functions, and let $C_0(X)$ be the set of all continuous functions that vanishes at infinity. Both $C_b(X)$ and $C_0(X)$ are Banach spaces equipped with uniform norm.

By Riesz representation theorem (Theorem 6.19 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis), $C_0(X)^* = \mathcal{M}(X)$, the set of regular Borel measures of bounded variation. From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3938193), $C_b(X)^* = rba(X)$, the set of regular, finitely additive signed measures of bounded variation. Both dual spaces are equipped with total variation norm, and furthermore, $\mathcal{M}(X) \subseteq rba(X)$.

My confusion is that, since $C_0(X)$ is a subspace of $C_b(X)$, $C_b(X)^*$ should be a subspace of $C_0(X)^*$. This implies that $C_b(X)^* = C_0(X)^* = \mathcal{M}(X)$. Is it reasonable, or where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why should $C_b(X)^\ast$ be a subspace of $C_0(X)^\ast$? Since $C_0(X) \subseteq C_b(X)$, there is a natural restriction map $C_b(X)^\ast \to C_0(X)^\ast$. It is surjective per Hahn-Banach, but there’s no reason why it has to be injective. (In fact, it is very much not injective, also per Hahn-Banach.)

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to claim that if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ (both normed, or even Banach), then $X^*$ is (isomorphic to) a subspace of $Y^*$? This isn't true already for $Y=\{0\}$ and $X=\Bbb R$ (or take $Y=\Bbb R$ and $X=\Bbb R^2$ if you don't like the trivial space).

Comment: Thank you. I was misled by $L^p$ spaces, which does not constitite an exanple at all.